# getting id from href html action php

Tags: php

Why it doesn't execute the command?

the action:

```
 <td> <?php echo "<a href='action.scripts.php?actiune=delete&id='".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>" ?></td>
```

here:

```
  else if ($_GET['actiune'] ==="delete"){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "$id";
    //echo "lsls";
    // $query = mysql_query("delete from user where id= '$id'");
//     if ($query){
//      echo "User deleted";
//     }
}
```

And it doesn't print the id. Why?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($row['id'])` to see what it's returning?

Comment: why doesn't you try by `if ` ,it's else if ?

Comment: Can you show what is in the $_GET array and what the link is when its printed in the html ?

Comment: What is the if condition before else if ? I think else if is not executing

Comment: are you sure that you have any value assigned into `$row['id']`? what `view source` tells you on that row?

Comment: try to use == instead of === and write here result

Answer (score 1):

You have additional single quote `'` in your href parameter id !remove it

```
<td> <?php echo "<a href='action.scripts.php?actiune=delete&id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>" ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
$row['id'] = 'some value';
$row = $row['id'];

<td> <?php echo "<a href='action.scripts.php?actiune=delete&id=$row'>Delete</a>" ?></td>
```

Comment: this worked: <td><a href="action.scripts.php?actiune=delete&id=<?php echo $id;?>">delete</a></td>

Answer (score -2):

you are using wrong format

```
else if ($_GET['actiune'] =="delete"){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "$id";
```

use this

```
else if ($_GET['actiune'] =="delete"){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
```

Comment: there is no difference between `echo "$id"` and `echo $id`;